# Enqueuing multiple style sheets in Wordpress child theme

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I have several Wordpress sites set up and have child themes created for all of them. One of the sites is going to have multiple subsites that will all include customized branding. I have a style sheet enqueued in my child theme with the following code in my functions.php file.

```
if ( !function_exists( 'chld_thm_cfg_locale_css' ) ):
function chld_thm_cfg_locale_css( $uri ){
    if ( empty( $uri ) && is_rtl() && file_exists( get_template_directory() . '/rtl.css' ) )
        $uri = get_template_directory_uri() . '/rtl.css';
    return $uri;
}
endif;
add_filter( 'locale_stylesheet_uri', 'chld_thm_cfg_locale_css' );

if ( !function_exists( 'chld_thm_cfg_parent_css' ) ):
function chld_thm_cfg_parent_css() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'chld_thm_cfg_parent', trailingslashit( get_template_directory_uri() ) . 'style.css', array( 'font-awesome','swiper','perfect-scrollbar','animate' ) );
}
endif;
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'chld_thm_cfg_parent_css', 10 );
```

This works fine and my style sheet is functioning as expected. The issue I'm running in to is as I add new subsites with customized branding, the size of this style sheet, style.css, is getting harder to manage. What I want to do is enqueue another style sheet in my child theme for the subsites. I tried to replicate the code above to enqueue the new style sheet, but it does not work. Here is what I added in my functions.php file immediately below the code above:

```
if ( !function_exists( 'coastal_thm_cfg_locale_css' ) ):
function coastal_thm_cfg_locale_css( $uri ){
    if ( empty( $uri ) && is_rtl() && file_exists( get_template_directory() . '/rtl.css' ) )
        $uri = get_template_directory_uri() . '/rtl.css';
    return $uri;
}
endif;
add_filter( 'locale_stylesheet_uri', 'coastal_thm_cfg_locale_css' );

if ( !function_exists( 'coastal_thm_cfg_parent_css' ) ):
function coastal_thm_cfg_parent_css() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'coastal_thm_cfg_parent', trailingslashit( get_template_directory_uri() ) . 'coastal-style.css', array( 'font-awesome','swiper','perfect-scrollbar','animate' ) );
}
endif;
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'coastal_thm_cfg_parent_css', 11 );
```

I thought this would work but it does not. I understand child themes but must admin the whole enqueuing process is quite confusing to me. I used a plugin, Child Theme Configurator, to enqueue the primary child theme style sheet.

I've looked through several blog posts and questions in Stackoverflow, but cannot find an answer to the specific problem.

Is enqueuing multiple style sheets like this possible?

If so, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's not clear from you description that this is really a best solution for your issue - adding a new stylesheet to organize "branding" styles for sub-sites - but, leaving that question aside, I don't understand why you're not just enqueuing the "special" stylesheet like any other stylesheet, with whatever relevant conditions.

Comment: CK - i may ditch the idea altogether and just keep everything organized all in one style sheet. my reason for testing this approach is to manage future growth where i could have several dozen subsites that need customized styling. that being said, i'm still curious how to get the second style sheet enqueued in case i need that solution for this or something else going forward. when you say "i don't understand why you're not just enqueuing the "special" styleseet like any other stylesheet..." what about my solution doesn't followo your suggestion?

Comment: You'd just enqueue a new stylesheet in the same way that any stylesheet is enqueued,from within the child theme typically a two-part wp_enqueue_scripts action and function. https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/ On the other hand, there are different ways to go about organizing and differentiating sub-sites and conditionally loading styles. What's best for your project will depend entirely on what you're trying to achieve.